# ¿Como unir cada 2 registros de una tabla en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que cada 2 registros se junten o no se si haya una forma mas facil de hacerlo pero necesito agrupar cada 2 lineas para juntar la fila que dice activated y desactivated, para asi tener en una sola fila cuando se activo y desactivo de una linea y estacion.

No se si alguien pueda ayudarme, se los agradezco!

Comment: ¿Has pensado que pasaría si tienes dos o más acciones iguales seguidas?

Comment: Asi es, pero aun no logro hacer una coincidencia, no se si haya una forma de hacer esto un poco mas facil